# perl oops program for student, their marks and percentages

Tags: perl, oop, class

I am newbie in perl. I have a program to do.

1.I want to create a simple class which will have information of student name, roll no and 6 subject marks.
2.I also want to create a subroutine to calculate percentages of the marks.
3.Also wants to demonstrate user inheritance by creating child class which will have roll no, name from parent class and addition of new field address and phone no..
4. create a method overriding for percentage subroutine.

I gone through many perl docs but yet unable to get through this and I am unable to solve 2, 3 and 4 too.

My till now code is pasted below but that also seems not working. Can anyone let me know how can I do this program so that I can learn abt all this?

My Code :

```
class.pm  

package class;

#constructor
sub new 
{
#my ($class) = @_;
my ($class, %arg) = @_;
my $self = 
{
    _name => $arg{_name}    ,
    _roll_no => $arg{_roll_no}    ,
    _sub1 => $arg{_sub1}    ,
    _sub2 => $arg{_sub2}    ,
    _sub3 => $arg{_sub3}    ,
    _sub4 => $arg{_sub4}    ,
    _sub5 => $arg{_sub5}    ,
    _sub6 => $arg{_sub6}    
};
, $class;
}  

sub name        { $_[0] -> {_name}     }
sub roll_no     { $_[0] -> {_roll_no} }
sub sub1    { $_[0] -> {_sub1}}
sub sub2    { $_[0] -> {_sub2}}
sub sub3    { $_[0] -> {_sub3}}
sub sub4    { $_[0] -> {_sub4}}
sub sub5    { $_[0] -> {_sub5}}
sub sub6    { $_[0] -> {_sub6}}

1;
```

I have also created class1.pm

```
class1.pm


use class;

print "Object 1:\n\n";

my $obj1 = class->new(
name => "sam"    ,
roll_no => "1"    ,
sub1 => "99"    ,
sub2 => "98"    ,
sub3 => "97"    ,
sub4 => "96"    ,
sub5 => "95"    ,
sub6 => "96" 
);


print $obj1->name, "\n";
print $obj1->roll_no, "\n";
print $obj1->sub1, "\n";
print $obj1->sub2, "\n";
print $obj1->sub3, "\n";
print $obj1->sub4, "\n";
print $obj1->sub5, "\n";
print $obj1->sub6, "\n";
```

Comment: Since you are a student, my best advice is to use the perl debugger (command line perl -d) and go step by step trough your code, looking at the variables you set. You will quickly find what's wrong and learn much more than getting a ready answer.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` should be at the top of all your perl files if you want to stay sane.

Comment: even the code is not complete coz i am not able to understand how to do those things

Comment: If "also seems not working" is the best of your diagnostic abilities, you have problems ahead. You could at least mention any error message you get.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the class fixed to make your testing code work:

```
package class;

sub new {
    my ($class, %arg) = @_;

    my $self = {
        _name    => $arg{name},
        _roll_no => $arg{roll_no},
        _sub1    => $arg{sub1},
        _sub2    => $arg{sub2},
        _sub3    => $arg{sub3},
        _sub4    => $arg{sub4},
        _sub5    => $arg{sub5},
        _sub6    => $arg{sub6}
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub name    { $_[0]->{_name} }
sub roll_no { $_[0]->{_roll_no} }
sub sub1    { $_[0]->{_sub1} }
sub sub2    { $_[0]->{_sub2} }
sub sub3    { $_[0]->{_sub3} }
sub sub4    { $_[0]->{_sub4} }
sub sub5    { $_[0]->{_sub5} }
sub sub6    { $_[0]->{_sub6} }
```

There were two things that needed to be fixed:

- you were not [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html)ing the instance - this really makes the reference belong to the class
- parameters from `%args` had extra underlines - in your example, you are passing `name => "sam"`, not `_name => "sam"`

Couple more notes:

- the lowercase package names in perl are typically used by pragmas. Better practice is to use CamelCase for class naming
- there are tons of modules that helps you with class definition like above [Class::Accessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3A%3AAccessor) to more complex OO builders like [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose). With latter, your class definition would look like:

  ```
  package class;
  use Moose;

  has name    => (is => 'ro');
  has roll_no => (is => 'ro');
  has sub1    => (is => 'ro');
  has sub2    => (is => 'ro');
  has sub3    => (is => 'ro');
  has sub4    => (is => 'ro');
  has sub5    => (is => 'ro');
  has sub6    => (is => 'ro');
  ```

`has` declares an attribute for you and you get constructor for free.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to use [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) to bless the `$self` to the object in `new`. A simple example of a proper ctor definition can be found [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node125.html#SECTION001562000000000000000).